# Is there a built in/standard way to create a view of a versioned list at a specific date?

Tags: list, list-view

I have a list which has versioned items. I like to create a view of the list which shows the state of the list at a specific date/time, i.e. a list with

- exactly the items which existed at that date/time
- the version of the item being the version at that date/time

(I could make an external copy, but i would like to use a standard method working without external tools if possible)

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to create a list view with all the requirements you specified.

If you want to show the number of items in standard view you can do that using view settings.

[image]

You can also see all the versions of specific list item from ellipses (...) within list view (I think you know this already!) - Not filtered by the specific date/time as you want.